# Azure Active Directory and Federated Authentication

Tags: azure, active-directory, windows-authentication, adfs, azure-active-directory

We're using Azure Active Directory with Federated Authentication. This is working without a problem - but we need the ability to have users sign in with credentials other than their logged in Windows credentials.

What happens right now is

- User navigates to our web app and the Azure ADAL for JavaScript attempts to log in
- The user is redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=xxxx&client-request-id=xxxx&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.2&nonce=xxxx
- The user is presented with a username and password box.
- Upon entering the username (even if it is someone else's username) (as soon as focus is lost from the username textbox), the page shows

> It looks like this email is used with more than one account from
>   Microsoft. Which one do you want to use? Work or school account    Work
>   or school account Assigned by your work or school

- Upon clicking "Work or school account", the user is presented with

> Redirecting We're taking you to your organization's sign-in page.

- The page redirects to the url

https://ds1.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?username=me%40mydomain.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%xxxxx&popupui=1

- The user is automatically logged in using their active Windows credentials (even if they entered a different username on the previous page).

If I navigate to the URL https://ds1.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?username=me%40mydomain.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%xxxxx&popupui=1 using a Windows session with a non-domain (local) account, I get a standard Integrated Authentication prompt

[image]
So - it seems like our ADFS server is using Integrated Windows Authentication on an IIS Website.

My question is - how can I allow the user to log in as a different domain user for the web app. Is there a special ADFS login URL I can use? And if so, how do I tell the Azure app to use that URL. Or is there a way to disable Integrated Authentication in some other way, on demand?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I see that if I point the ADFS URL to the basic auth endpoint

https://ds1.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/auth/***basic***/?username=me%40mydomain.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%xxxxx&popupui=1

I am prompted for basic authentication (exactly what I want)...so how do I tell my Azure AD or Azure AD App what login URL to use? And how can I control it conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is actually pretty simple (with some help from Fiddler):

Add &prompt=login to the query string generated by the ADAL JavaScript when redirecting to login.microsoftonline.com. This causes the MS portal to redirect to the ADFS Forms Auth URL instead of the one using integrated security.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to either remove AD FS from the Local Intranet zone on the relevant machines so they prompt, or better, look in to the User Agent based targeting in AD FS and configure those machines to send a User Agent that triggers Forms Based AuthN.

Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727110.aspx for more info on this.

Comment: How does SharePoint do it when I hit sign in as a different user? It displays the integrated authentication prompt, not forms auth.

Comment: Federated SharePoint or you're talking about a traditional SharePoint on-premises install that uses WIA?

Comment: Traditional. I realize it's not the same, but somehow it does manage to bypass integrated auth in certain situations and re prompt the user for Windows credentials

Comment: Also, do you know what controls exactly what adfs page the Microsoft login page redirects to? I found that if I mess with the adfs URL, I can force it to use basic, forms or certificate authentication. So I just need a way of contextually controlling what adfs login page is used.